# Elegant way to update multiple values for Sqlite3 Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have an `Sqlite3` database called **MYTABLE** like this:

[image]

My objective is to update the values of  **COUNT** column by simply adding the existing value with the new value.

There will be two inputs that I will recieve:

1. Firstly, a list of IDs that I need to update  for **COUNT** column.
   For example: ['1','3','2','5']
2. And Secondly, the number of count to be added to the every IDs in
   the list above.

So far, the best I can come up with is:

```
#my input1, the list of IDs that need updating
id_list = ['1','2','5','3']

#my input2, the value to be added to the existing count value
new_count = 3

#empty list to store the original count values before updating
original_counts = []

#iterate through the input1 and retrieve the original count values
for item in id_list :
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT from MYTABLE where ID=?",[item])
    for row in cursor:
        original_counts.append(row[0])

#iterate through the input1 and update the count values
for i in range(len(id_list )):
    conn.execute("UPDATE MYTABLE set COUNT = ? where ID=?",[original_counts[i]+new_count ,mylist[i])
```

Is there better/more elegent and more efficient way to achieve what I want?

### UPDATE 1:

I have tried this based on N Reed's answer(not exactly the same) like this and it worked!

```
for item in mylist:
    conn.execute("UPDATE MYTABLE set VAL=VAL+? where ID=?",[new_count,item])
```

**Take Away for me** is we can update a value in `sqlite3` based on it's current value(which I didn't know)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE set COUNT = COUNT + 5 where ID in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I don't know python that well, but you probably want code in python something like:

```
conn.execute("UPDATE MYTABLE set COUNT = COUNT + ? where ID in (?)", new_count , ",".join(mylist))
```

Keep  in mind there is a limit to the number of items you can have in the Id list with sqllite (I think it is something like 1000)

Also be very careful about sql injection when you are creating queries this way. You probably will want to make sure that all the items in mylist have already been escaped somewhere else.

I also recommend against having a column called 'count' as it is a keyword in sql.

Comment: @N Reed Is `COUNT = COUNT + ?` that you used in second line a valid query statement? The column "Count" is just something i made up for the sake of simplicity. My actual database has proper name which doesn't conflict with any keyword. Thanks for pointing out though.Also, length of my ID list will always be less than 100 so it shoudn't be a problem.

Comment: @N Reed Sorry, but I could not get your second line to work as I get the error message along the line of "2 arguments expected - 3 given". So, after modifying a bit(pls see my update) I managed get it work.